# ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyer error appears after the deletion was purposefully prevented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Customer model that has many Purchase Orders. In the model, before deleting a customer it checks to make sure that the customer has no associated PO's and prevents deletion if it does. Now I've used this almost exact same code on other models without a problem, but with this model if I try to delete a customer with PO's I get that white and red screen saying  an ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed error was thrown on `if company.destroy` instead of being redirected to the customer page with a nice flash warning.


**model/company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :account_owner, counter_cache: true
  has_many :purchase_orders

  before_destroy :po_check

  private   

  def po_check
    !self.purchase_orders.any?
  end
end
```

**controllers/companies_controller.rb**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    company = Company.find(params[:id])
    if company.destroy
      flash[:success] = company.name + ' deleted.'
      redirect_to companies_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Cannot delete companies associated with Purchase Orders'
      redirect_to company
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a Rails version issue.  Rails 4.1.6 says it will raise that error if you do what you're doing.

You could also use `:dependent` to accomplish this.  Example:

```
has_many :purchase_orders, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

From the documentation:

> :dependent Controls what happens to the associated objects when their
>   owner is destroyed. Note that these are implemented as callbacks, and
>   Rails executes callbacks in order. Therefore, other similar callbacks
>   may affect the :dependent behavior, and the :dependent behavior may
>   affect other callbacks.
>
> :destroy causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed.
>
> :delete_all causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly
>   from the database (so callbacks will not be executed).
>
> :nullify causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not
>   executed.
>
> :restrict_with_exception causes an exception to be raised if there are
>   any associated records.
>
> :restrict_with_error causes an error to be added to the owner if there
>   are any associated objects.

Comment: I just discovered this before you posted! Doesn't answer the question about the inconsistent behavior though. Why would it raise an exception for one model but an error for the other two? Ultimately though, those other two models will be migrated over to the way you mentioned.

Comment: @TheThird Oh, it's the same app, but different models?  That is strange.  You'd have to post more code to clarify.

Comment: I've noticed unexpected behaviour when using `dependent: :restrict_with_error`, it can raise the `RecordNotDestroyed` error.  For example: _ObjectA_, has a `:destroy` relationship with _ObjectB_, while ObjectB has a :`restrict_with_error` relationship to _ObjectC_.  Calling `ObjectB.destroy` DIRECTLY when there are _ObjectC_ dependents adds an error to `ObjectB.errors` (EXPECTED).  However, calling `ObjectA.destroy` when it has a dependent _ObjectB_ instance (same as the one described above) raises a `RecordNotDestroyed` error instead of adding a message to `ObjectA.errors`.  (Rails-4.2.6)

Comment: @Dan on a related note in Rails-4.2.7, you can even run into this error using `dependent: :destroy` on a has_many relationship, see [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18056). It's quite confusing to have an error raised when using `destroy`.